# Disable directory listing in OpenCPU

Tags: opencpu, rapache

I have been trying to disable directory listing in OpenCPU so our users cannot see the resulting directories and files in the `http://server/ocpu/tmp/` directory.

I have followed  [Apache's Directory Listing Configuration](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings) and deleted every mention of `Indexes` in the `conf` files in `/etc/apache2/` and included `Options -Indexes` in the `sites-enabled/opencpu.conf` file (in the Location tags) without success.

I also looked at the rApache documention without finding any pertinent entry.

Does anyone know any documentation or configuration to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory listing is done dynamically by R code so Apache configs won't help here.

If you run the OpenCPU cloud server under Ubuntu directory listing of `/ocpu/tmp` is disabled by default via the apparmor configurations. Try it:

```
https://cloud.opencpu.org/ocpu/tmp/
```

This only works if your platform supports AppArmor, so it doesn't work for CentOS or Docker. Therefore Ubuntu deployment is recommended for production.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.

Sadly, our servers run OpenCPU inside Docker (with a Debian image) within a RedHat server.

Is there any other way to enforce the listing? Maybe using Docker's Apparmor or modifying the R code before building?